# Angular 4 file chooser

Tags: angular, events

I have a project were i need to add a document to an API by a button

But right now i just need that the button opens the file chooser and let me select the file and returns me the name of it.

I have this button assigned with the event.

So can someone please help me with the code to open the file finder please?, i'm a begginer of angular.

Button:

`<button (click)="myEvent($event)">Add Document</button>`

Event:

```
 myEvent (event) {
 console.log(event); }
```

Thanks in advance, David.

Comment: You need to use an `<input type="file" />`

Answer (score 5):

You need

```
<input type="file"  multiple="multiple" (change)="change($event)">
```

And in your .ts file you can get:

```
change(event:any) {
console.log(event.target.files);
}
```